# Passing content from controller to custom directive present outside of the controller

Tags: angularjs

How i can pass content from controller to custom directive which is present outside of the controller.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="addcontent">
<a href="#" ng-click="addcontenttobox('1234567')">add content 1234567</a>
</div>
<outside-box></outside-box>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('addcontent', function ($scope) {
$scope.addcontenttobox = function(content){
        $scope.msg = content;
    }
});
```

directive

```
    angular.module('myApp')
.directive('outsideBox', function () {
 return {
    templateUrl : "msg.html",

};
});
```

msg.html

```
Number - {{msg}}
```

Comment: have you tried $rootScope like this $rootScope.msg = content;

Answer (score 0):

You should read about scopes in directives. You can pass your data to directives using scopes. Isolated Scope should do the task for you. Read over here.

https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/